# Low duty cycle 12VDC to 120VAC inverter

Tags: motor, inverter

I need to operate a small 120VAC motor for short bursts of 1 to 3 seconds using a 12VDC supply (it's for a remote antenna switch).

Operations are typically minutes to hours apart, so the duty cycle is *very* low.  I don't know the precise power draw but it's likely in the 10-15 watt range, so not very great.

A typical inverter seems like overkill where the average power requirement is so small.  In my mind I picture some caps storing energy for the output pulses, but I can't picture a nice implementation.

Any suggestions for a simple and physically compact circuit that could handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Before you start specing anything out you should scope the actual current draw of the motor as it starts up. Inrush currents can be pretty serious.

Comment: possibly a step down transformer with centre tap on LV side used in reverse with Q,Q! to driver transistors on each leg.

Comment: The inrush current thing is a good point.  I'll try to check that tomorrow.  I suppose putting a scope in single-sweep peak-hold mode across a small resistor in series with the power lead to catch the voltage drop would be a good way to characterize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your motor can tolerate a square wave, it is fairly easy to create a push-pull driver connected to a center-tapped transformer. You can use a transformer normally used for step-down reversed as a step-up.

I successfully drove my telescope synchronous motor with a DIY circuit as I described. Sorry, I don't know where the schematic is.

Edit: Here is a circuit that will create a modified square wave (less harmonics, better than what I built). This is untested, you shouldn't attempt this unless you have some experience.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXAl9D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output should look like this:

[image]